# TypeError Illegal offset type vaildator for images mimes types

Tags: php, laravel

The following code will verify whether an image is a JPG, JPEG, or PNG.

I tried to upload a jpeg file, but the validator somehow throws an error.

```php
 $validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            $request->file('image1') => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
            $request->file('image2') => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
            $request->file('image3') => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
            $request->file('image4') => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
          ]);
        //  dd($validate[0]);
         if( $validate->fails() ){
          return response($validate->errors(), 400);
         }
```

how the request appears It receives 4 photos and is supposed to verify whether they are images before uploading them to the server.

```
+files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#55 ▼
    #parameters: array:4 [▼
      "image1" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#37 ▼
        -test: false
        -originalName: "2.jpeg"
        -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
        -error: 0
        path: "/private/var/tmp"
        filename: "php4m2tRN"
        basename: "php4m2tRN"
        pathname: "/private/var/tmp/php4m2tRN"
        extension: ""
        realPath: "/private/var/tmp/php4m2tRN"
        aTime: 2023-02-23 18:48:09
        mTime: 2023-02-23 18:48:09
        cTime: 2023-02-23 18:48:09
        inode: 1342583
        size: 45014
        perms: 0100600
        owner: 501
        group: 0
        type: "file"
        writable: true
        readable: true
        executable: false
        file: true
        dir: false
        link: false
      }
      "image2" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#38 ▶}
      "image3" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#39 ▶}
      "image4" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#40 ▶}
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to create the Validator would be to add the file names as keys https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

```
$validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'image1' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
            'image2' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
           'image3' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
            'image4' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
          ]);
```

Comment: I would even argue to use `$request->validate`, no need to `Validator::make`, etc

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes, you are right that is also a possibility, your approach comes with the benefit of writing less code, which is useful for simple usecases like the above where we need to validate, take the validation messages out of the lang folder and simply redirect back.